# 2D section plane through free 3D point data (Python)

Tags: python, python-3.x, plotly, plotly-python

Good day

I have been trying to solve the following problem for two days now. Unfortunately I am not an expert. Still, I allow myself to try to describe my problem here and be thankful for any help.

I have measurement data z (`eps_xx`) to specific x and y coordinates. You can see the format represented below as Pandas Dataframe:

```
      Node [-]   x [m]   y [m]    eps_xx [-]
0            1  0.0096  0.0089  8.310000e-07
1            2  0.0000  0.0089  1.317000e-07
2            3  0.0000  0.0000  8.104000e-07
3            4  0.0096  0.0000  2.465000e-06
4            5  0.0192  0.0000  6.276000e-06
...        ...     ...     ...           ...
2314      2315  0.7700  0.1333 -7.269000e-06
2315      2316  0.7700  0.1426 -6.697000e-06
2316      2317  0.7700  0.1499 -3.587000e-06
2317      2318  0.7700  0.1520  6.296000e-07
2318      2319  0.7700  0.1600 -2.000000e-06
```

The points of the x and y coordinates do not follow any pattern and are freely distributed.
I would like to create a 3D surface plot from this data (preferably in plotly but matplolib is also OK). A scatter plot I have already done:

```py
import pandas as pd
import plotly.graph_objects as go

# Read data from Excel file
df = pd.read_excel('Data.xlsx', sheet_name="Step_5")
print(df)

# Extract x, y, z values from data frame
x = df['x [m]'].values
y = df['y [m]'].values
z = df['eps_xx [-]'].values

# Create a 3D scatter plot with the vertical plane
fig = go.Figure()

# Add the scatter plot trace
fig.add_trace(go.Scatter3d(x=x, y=y, z=z, mode='markers', marker=dict(size=3)))

# Set plot layout
fig.update_layout(scene=dict(xaxis_title='x [m]', yaxis_title='y [m]', zaxis_title='eps_xx [-]'))

# Display plot
fig.show()
```

[image: Scatter Plot of data]

1. But because the x and y points are freely distributed, the first thing I can't do now is to create a surface plot with `go.Surface(x=x, y=y, z=z)`.
2. After I succeed in creating a surface from these 3D measurement points, I would like to generate a 2D plot from it along a given vertical plane. Actually exactly as it can be found in this article:
   [Wanted Solution like in this article](https://community.plotly.com/t/slicing-3d-surface-plot-along-a-user-selected-axis/40771/6), Picture:

[image: Wanted Solution with export of the data in the 2D Graph as Pandas Dataframe]

Unfortunately, this article works with functions and not with point measurement data.

3. The last step would be to get this new 2D data points of the cutted Plot into a Pandas Dataframe again.

Maybe quite a bit of math needs to be done by hand in the background and just displaying the results in Plotly. In my research so far I only hoped that there is already a prefabricated library for such cutting operations in free 3D space. Linear interpolation can be performed between the data points

I tried already several ways to solve my Problem. I used different libraries like numpy, scipy or scikit-learn and tried various code examples I found. But for 3D point data I really didn't found anything suitable.

Thank you for your help!

Comment: You have not defined what plane of intersection you want to plot, and you don't have much data here - so this isn't really reproducible. If you can define the plane and link data then you'll get better help.

Comment: Thanks for your post @Reinderien. But the data doesn't really matter. It can be any points in 3D space. Also the cutting plane should be flexible as any desired.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By luck, a friend came to visit this evening and I was able to ask him. I am therefore posting here the solution that now works for me. Perhaps my request will also be useful for someone else.

The solution for me came with `from scipy.interpolate import LinearNDInterpolator`. With this function it is possible to interpolate over the point data `Interpolation = LinearNDInterpolator(list(zip(x, y)), z)`.

With the now available function `Interpolation` I can calculate the values along an axis existing out of individual points:

```
    for i in range(0, len(x)):
         z = Interpolation(x[i], y[i])
```

At the end I can now display the individual data in a 3D-Plot with plotly ([Final result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cC5mx.png)) and have also the data aviable in the back as dataframes for further calculations.

Thanks a lot for the help anyway. Wish you all successful coding.